# React-redux-firebase loads data correctly but isnt available inside component

Tags: firebase, redux, react-redux-firebase

Following scheme from https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase (go to **Queries Based On Props** paragraph).

Code responsible for fetching data from the firebase:

```
export default compose(
  firebaseConnect((props) => [
    `offers/${props.params.userId}`,
  ]),
  connect((state, props) => {
    console.log(state.get('firebase')) // <--- logs data correctly
    return {
      user: get(state.get('firebase'), `offers/${props.params.userId}`),
    };
  })
)(UserProfile);
```

If you wonder what's the `.get` - state is an immutable Map.

[image]

**Issue**: As you can see, the data fetches properly, but component doesn't get re-rendered. Seems like props haven't changed.

**Q**: How to force component to update and to receive props properly?

Thank u!

Comment: Correct me if I am mistaken, doesn't `get(state.get('firebase')` return a promise? And you're trying to assign an unfulfilled promise to `user`? Anyhow, it may be preferable to have your data-fetching occur in an action creator, then passing that payload to a reducer to which you `connect` and do your mapping or dispatching to props.

Comment: Also, is it intentional that your `console.log(state.get('firebase'))` differs from `(user: get(state.get('firebase'))`?

Comment: @NoMoreQuestions Hmm, with 90% sure `firebase` is an object. And it's likely the same as I would destructure it as it's shown in the docs (`({ firebase })`). Also mind that `firebase` is already a connected reducer, with built-in action creators.

Comment: @NoMoreQuestions Yes, it's just copy-paste from official docs and it should.. work :/

Comment: A bit suspicious if your `console.log()` prints your data but `user` remains `undefined`. Have you changed these to be identical?

Comment: @NoMoreQuestions I will check it now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162630/discussion-between-nomorequestions-and-patrickkx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Together with **[NoMoreQuestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4716488/nomorequestions)** we have found a solution. I had to use `populate` function instead of `get`.

```
import { populate } from 'react-redux-firebase';
```

Weird that docs are saying something different about that.

Answer (score 1):

Author of `react-redux-firebase` here. Totally open to pull requests for changes to the docs to make this more clear.

Something to note: the original question uses v1.*.* syntax which is different from v2.*.* with respect to how things are stored in redux (Immutable.js is no longer used). This means that `state.get` is no longer a function.